# Close other panels when one of the panel opened in accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accordion

How to close all panel in the accordion when one of the panel opened? My panel Accordion is still open. The expectation is when i click the one of panel, other panel is automatically closed.

This is my HTML, CSS and JS

```js
$(".acitemx h3").click(function() {
  $header = $(this);
  $content = $header.next();
  $content.slideToggle(500, function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('current');
  });
});
$('.acitemx').eq(0).addClass('.acitemx').find('.accx').css('display', 'block');
```

```css
/* accordion editing */

.accx {
  background: #FFF none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
  padding: 15px;
  display: none;
}
.acitemx {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgb(189, 189, 189);
}
.acitemx h3 {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #00ADEF none repeat scroll 0% 0% !important;
  color: #FFF !important;
  font-family: "roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 8px 40px 8px 15px !important;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
}
/* end accordion editing */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="accordionx">
  <div class="acitemx">
    <h3>First Panel</h3>
    <div class="accx">
      This is the content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="acitemx">
    <h3>Second Panel</h3>
    <div class="accx">
      This is the content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="acitemx">
    <h3>Third Panel</h3>
    <div class="accx">
      This is the content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This the JSFiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/bupd32rq/3/

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `slideUp()` function after finding other siblings `accx` element.

```
$(this).parent().siblings().find('.accx').slideUp();
```

**Not related to answer:** 
`$('.acitemx').eq(0).addClass('.acitemx').find('.accx').css('display', 'block');` Here addClass need not have `.` and there is no logic adding another class of same name as they already have the CSS properties set.

[**JSfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ux7xadej/1/)

**Code snippet**

```js
$(".acitemx h3").click(function() {
  $header = $(this);
  $content = $header.next();
  $content.slideToggle(500, function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('current');
  });
  $(this).parent().siblings().find('.accx').slideUp(); // Added code
});
$('.acitemx').eq(0).find('.accx').css('display', 'block');
```

```css
/* accordion editing */

.accx {
  background: #FFF none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
  padding: 15px;
  display: none;
}
.acitemx {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgb(189, 189, 189);
}
.acitemx h3 {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #00ADEF none repeat scroll 0% 0% !important;
  color: #FFF !important;
  font-family: "roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 8px 40px 8px 15px !important;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
}
/* end accordion editing */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="accordionx">
  <div class="acitemx">
    <h3>First Panel</h3>
    <div class="accx">
      This is the content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="acitemx">
    <h3>Second Panel</h3>
    <div class="accx">
      This is the content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="acitemx">
    <h3>Third Panel</h3>
    <div class="accx">
      This is the content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```